# Using Gradle, how can I print how long each task took to execute?

Tags: gradle

Right now, for one of the gradle targets run frequently, the output looks like this:

```
:DataPlanner:clean
:common:clean
:server:clean
:simulator:clean
:util:clean
:util:compileJava
:util:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:util:classes
:util:compileTestJava
:util:processTestResources
:util:testClasses
:util:test
:util:jar
:common:compileJava
:common:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:common:classes
:common:compileTestJava
:common:processTestResources
```

How do I get it to look something more like this?

```
:DataPlanner:clean
took 2secs
:common:clean
took 2 secs
:server:clean
took 3 secs
:simulator:clean
took 4 secs
:util:clean
took 1 sec
...
```

If it's not possible to get every task to print its duration upon completion, printing the timestamp would be an acceptable alternative.

Any ideas?

Modifying one of the proposed solutions which didn't work for me, this one did:

```
gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
task.ext.setProperty("startTime", new java.util.Date())
}

gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
    int secs = ( new java.util.Date().getTime() - task.ext.startTime.getTime() ) / 1000
    int mins = secs / 60

    if ( 4 < secs ) {
        int sec = secs - mins * 60
        println " -> took " + mins + ( ( 1 == mins ) ? " min " : " mins " ) + sec + ( ( 1 == sec ) ? " sec" : " secs" )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add pre and post execution hooks to do this. Before task execution add the current time as a property on the task, and then after execution you can compare the current time to the saved time.

```
import java.time.*
gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
    task.ext.setProperty("startTime", Instant.now())
}

gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
    println task.name + " took " + Duration.between(task.ext.startTime, Instant.now()).toSeconds() + " seconds"
}
```

results in output like this:

```
$gradle clean
:clean
clean took 0.043000000 seconds
```

Comment: The above didn't work for me, but I found that with a little modification, I could make it work:    <pre>gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask { Task task ->
    task.ext.setProperty("startTime", new java.util.Date())
}

gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { Task task, TaskState state ->
    int secs = ( new java.util.Date().getTime() - task.ext.startTime.getTime() ) / 1000
    int mins = secs / 60
    
    if ( 4 < secs ) {
        int sec = secs - mins * 60
        println " -> took " + mins + ( ( 1 == mins ) ? " min " : " mins " ) + sec + ( ( 1 == sec ) ? " sec" : " secs" )
    }
}</pre>

Comment: @jasons2645  Sorry about that!  My version uses the new java 8 time library.  I should have mentioned that.

Comment: `beforeTask` and `afterTask` are deprecated. What is the up-to-date alternative ?

Answer (score 14):

I don't know how you got this specific output. However, you can use the `--profile` command line flag in order to get a report about your build. Then you'll get an html report located under build/reports/profile which in Gradle 2.3 looks like:

[image]

You can read more about it in Gradle documentation [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:profiling_build).

If you insist on getting the specific output you specified you can try using the `beforeTask` and `afterTask` taskGraph hooks to measure the time and print it out. Just note that you'll need to be cautious about it in case gradle will be executed in parallel mode.