# Android Studio Instant Run Issue

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-instant-run

Whenever I hit "Instant Run" icon **without** any modification to source code, I get 2-3 min avg build time with a message

> Instant Run applied code changes and restarted the app. Field Type Change.

I printed how long every task took using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30225806/826606) and pasted my logs here. I have highlighted the tasks that took longer than 1 second.

Can anyone please quickly go through the logs and tell me what is going on? What can I do to avoid these long instant run times? It is becoming practically impossible now to do development.

```
Executing tasks: [:baymax:assembleDevelopmentDebug]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.
:baymax:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
preBuild took 0.002000000 seconds
:baymax:preDevelopmentDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
preDevelopmentDebugBuild took 0.002000000 seconds
:baymax:checkDevelopmentDebugManifest
checkDevelopmentDebugManifest took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareAndroidVisitsCommonUnspecifiedLibrary
prepareAndroidVisitsCommonUnspecifiedLibrary took 0.015000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidDatabindingAdapters131Library
prepareComAndroidDatabindingAdapters131Library took 0.011000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidDatabindingLibrary131Library
prepareComAndroidDatabindingLibrary131Library took 0.010000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library took 0.016000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72531Library took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout102Library
prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout102Library took 0.007000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2531Library took 0.009000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2531Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportGridlayoutV72531Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library took 0.009000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72531Library took 0.008000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportPercent2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportPercent2531Library took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72531Library took 0.002000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library took 0.010000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library took 0.012000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library took 0.008000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library took 0.008000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library took 0.005000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2531Library
prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2531Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComBirbitAndroidPriorityJobqueue201Library
prepareComBirbitAndroidPriorityJobqueue201Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4220Library
prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4220Library took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGetbaseFloatingactionbutton1101Library
prepareComGetbaseFloatingactionbutton1101Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGetkeepsafeRelinkerRelinker122Library
prepareComGetkeepsafeRelinkerRelinker122Library took 0.008000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGithubBartekscAndroidPdfViewer240Library
prepareComGithubBartekscAndroidPdfViewer240Library took 0.009000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGithubBartekscPdfiumAndroid150Library
prepareComGithubBartekscPdfiumAndroid150Library took 0.006000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGithubChrisbanesPhotoView131Library
prepareComGithubChrisbanesPhotoView131Library took 0.018000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGithubDbachelderCreditCardEntry147Library
prepareComGithubDbachelderCreditCardEntry147Library took 0.011000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGithubJakeWhartonViewPagerIndicator241Library
prepareComGithubJakeWhartonViewPagerIndicator241Library took 0.013000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGithubRahatarmanahmedCircularprogressview250Library
prepareComGithubRahatarmanahmedCircularprogressview250Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1100Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1100Library took 0.014000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1100Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1100Library took 0.008000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1100Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1100Library took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1100Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1100Library took 0.002000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1100Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1100Library took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1100Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1100Library took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1100Library
prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1100Library took 0.008000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1100Library
prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1100Library took 0.019000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1100Library
prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1100Library took 0.014000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1100Library
prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1100Library took 0.015000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1100Library
prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1100Library took 0.014000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComIntercomAndroidComposer102Library
prepareComIntercomAndroidComposer102Library took 0.010000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComIntercomAndroidComposerGallery102Library
prepareComIntercomAndroidComposerGallery102Library took 0.019000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComJakewhartonButterknife810Library
prepareComJakewhartonButterknife810Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComKailashdabhiOmRecorder110Library
prepareComKailashdabhiOmRecorder110Library took 0.010000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview230Library
prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview230Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComSquareupLeakcanaryLeakcanaryAndroidNoOp15Library
prepareComSquareupLeakcanaryLeakcanaryAndroidNoOp15Library took 0.013000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComStripeStripeAndroid301Library
prepareComStripeStripeAndroid301Library took 0.011000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareComTwilioVideoAndroid101Library
prepareComTwilioVideoAndroid101Library took 0.005000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareFmJiecaoJiecaovideoplayer363Library
prepareFmJiecaoJiecaovideoplayer363Library took 0.009000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareIoBranchSdkAndroidLibrary280Library
prepareIoBranchSdkAndroidLibrary280Library took 0.002000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareIoIntercomAndroidIntercomSdk320Library
prepareIoIntercomAndroidIntercomSdk320Library took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareIoIntercomAndroidIntercomSdkBase320Library
prepareIoIntercomAndroidIntercomSdkBase320Library took 0.007000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareIoIntercomAndroidIntercomSdkGcm320Library
prepareIoIntercomAndroidIntercomSdkGcm320Library took 0.021000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid121Library
prepareIoReactivexRxandroid121Library took 0.011000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareIoRealmRealmAndroidLibrary231Library
prepareIoRealmRealmAndroidLibrary231Library took 0.006000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareNetHockeyappAndroidHockeySDK400Library
prepareNetHockeyappAndroidHockeySDK400Library took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareNetYprestoAndroidtranscoderAndroidTranscoder0110Library
prepareNetYprestoAndroidtranscoderAndroidTranscoder0110Library took 0.008000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
preBuild took 0.003000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
preReleaseBuild took 0.005000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:checkReleaseManifest
checkReleaseManifest took 0.009000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
preReleaseUnitTestBuild took 0.001000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library took 0.007000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1021Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1021Library took 0.004000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1021Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1021Library took 0.009000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1021Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1021Library took 0.006000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1021Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1021Library took 0.003000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1021Library
prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1021Library took 0.013000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:prepareReleaseDependencies
prepareReleaseDependencies took 0.003000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
compileReleaseAidl took 0.024000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
compileReleaseNdk took 0.003000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
compileLint took 0.002000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:copyReleaseLint NO-SOURCE
copyReleaseLint took 0.001000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
compileReleaseRenderscript took 0.019000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
generateReleaseBuildConfig took 0.007000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
generateReleaseResValues took 0.003000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
generateReleaseResources took 0.001000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
mergeReleaseResources took 0.332000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
processReleaseManifest took 0.008000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
processReleaseResources took 0.036000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
generateReleaseSources took 0.001000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard took 0.002000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:javaPreCompileRelease
javaPreCompileRelease took 0.001000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
compileReleaseJavaWithJavac took 0.045000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
extractReleaseAnnotations took 0.016000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
mergeReleaseShaders took 0.003000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
compileReleaseShaders took 0.008000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
generateReleaseAssets took 0.002000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
mergeReleaseAssets took 0.004000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
mergeReleaseProguardFiles took 0.001000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
packageReleaseRenderscript took 0.002000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
packageReleaseResources took 0.049000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
processReleaseJavaRes took 0.007000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease took 0.010000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease took 0.008000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
mergeReleaseJniLibFolders took 0.003000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease took 0.009000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease UP-TO-DATE
transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease took 0.014000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease took 0.007000000 seconds
:mixpanel-android-4.9.0:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
bundleRelease took 0.034000000 seconds
:baymax:prepareDevelopmentDebugDependencies
prepareDevelopmentDebugDependencies took 0.002000000 seconds
:baymax:compileDevelopmentDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
compileDevelopmentDebugRenderscript took 0.020000000 seconds
:baymax:generateDevelopmentDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
generateDevelopmentDebugResValues took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/mwajeeh/android/baymax/src/debug/google-services.json
processDevelopmentDebugGoogleServices took 0.010000000 seconds
:baymax:generateDevelopmentDebugResources
generateDevelopmentDebugResources took 0E-9 seconds
:baymax:mergeDevelopmentDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
mergeDevelopmentDebugResources took 0.700000000 seconds
:baymax:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDevelopmentDebug UP-TO-DATE
dataBindingProcessLayoutsDevelopmentDebug took 0.277000000 seconds
:baymax:buildInfoDevelopmentDebugLoader
buildInfoDevelopmentDebugLoader took 0.016000000 seconds
:baymax:compileDevelopmentDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
compileDevelopmentDebugAidl took 0.064000000 seconds
:baymax:nodeSetup UP-TO-DATE
nodeSetup took 0.445000000 seconds
:baymax:installApolloCodegen
apollo-android@0.0.1 /Users/mwajeeh/android/baymax
-- apollo-codegen@0.10.5 


`**installApolloCodegen took 17.282000000 seconds**<<<<<<<<<<<<`


:baymax:generateDevelopmentDebugApolloIR UP-TO-DATE
generateDevelopmentDebugApolloIR took 0.015000000 seconds
:baymax:generateDevelopmentDebugApolloClasses UP-TO-DATE
generateDevelopmentDebugApolloClasses took 0.008000000 seconds
:baymax:generateDevelopmentDebugBuildConfig
generateDevelopmentDebugBuildConfig took 0.023000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebugManifest
processDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebugManifest took 0.462000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
processDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebugResources took 0.085000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentArmeabi-v7aDebugManifest
processDevelopmentArmeabi-v7aDebugManifest took 0.386000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentArmeabi-v7aDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
processDevelopmentArmeabi-v7aDebugResources took 0.173000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentUniversalDebugManifest
processDevelopmentUniversalDebugManifest took 0.591000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentUniversalDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
processDevelopmentUniversalDebugResources took 0.100000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentX86DebugManifest
processDevelopmentX86DebugManifest took 0.416000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentX86DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
processDevelopmentX86DebugResources took 0.082000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentX86_64DebugManifest
processDevelopmentX86_64DebugManifest took 0.461000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentX86_64DebugResources UP-TO-DATE
processDevelopmentX86_64DebugResources took 0.161000000 seconds
:baymax:generateDevelopmentDebugSources
generateDevelopmentDebugSources took 0.006000000 seconds
:baymax:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDevelopmentDebug
dataBindingExportBuildInfoDevelopmentDebug took 0.201000000 seconds
:baymax:incrementalDevelopmentDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard


`**incrementalDevelopmentDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard took 1.952000000 seconds**<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`


:baymax:javaPreCompileDevelopmentDebug
javaPreCompileDevelopmentDebug took 0.010000000 seconds
:baymax:transformClassesAndDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDevelopmentDebug UP-TO-DATE
transformClassesAndDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDevelopmentDebug took 0.212000000 seconds
:baymax:compileDevelopmentDebugJavaWithJavac
.... 
couple of warnings about "View field image collides with a variable or import"
  25 warnings
...


`**compileDevelopmentDebugJavaWithJavac took 106.659000000 seconds**<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`


:baymax:mergeDevelopmentDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
mergeDevelopmentDebugShaders took 0.044000000 seconds
:baymax:compileDevelopmentDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
compileDevelopmentDebugShaders took 0.023000000 seconds
:baymax:generateDevelopmentDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
generateDevelopmentDebugAssets took 0.016000000 seconds
:baymax:mergeDevelopmentDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
mergeDevelopmentDebugAssets took 0.248000000 seconds
:baymax:processDevelopmentDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
processDevelopmentDebugJavaRes took 0.002000000 seconds
:baymax:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDevelopmentDebug UP-TO-DATE
transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDevelopmentDebug took 0.036000000 seconds
:baymax:packageInstantRunResourcesDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebug UP-TO-DATE
packageInstantRunResourcesDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebug took 0.155000000 seconds
:baymax:fastDeployDevelopmentDebugExtractor UP-TO-DATE
fastDeployDevelopmentDebugExtractor took 0.006000000 seconds
:baymax:generateDevelopmentDebugInstantRunAppInfo UP-TO-DATE
generateDevelopmentDebugInstantRunAppInfo took 0.044000000 seconds
:baymax:checkManifestChangesDevelopmentDebug
checkManifestChangesDevelopmentDebug took 0.025000000 seconds
:baymax:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDevelopmentDebug UP-TO-DATE
transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDevelopmentDebug took 0.051000000 seconds
:baymax:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDevelopmentDebug
transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDevelopmentDebug took 30.824000000 seconds
:baymax:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDevelopmentDebug
transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDevelopmentDebug took 0.526000000 seconds
:baymax:transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDevelopmentDebug UP-TO-DATE
transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDevelopmentDebug took 0.039000000 seconds
:baymax:compileDevelopmentDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
compileDevelopmentDebugNdk took 0.018000000 seconds
:baymax:mergeDevelopmentDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
mergeDevelopmentDebugJniLibFolders took 0.012000000 seconds
:baymax:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDevelopmentDebug UP-TO-DATE
transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDevelopmentDebug took 0.075000000 seconds
:baymax:transformNativeLibsAndResourcesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDevelopmentDebug UP-TO-DATE
transformNativeLibsAndResourcesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDevelopmentDebug took 0.008000000 seconds
:baymax:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDevelopmentDebug


`**transformClassesWithInstantRunForDevelopmentDebug took 1.158000000 seconds**<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`


:baymax:transformClassesEnhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDevelopmentDebug
transformClassesEnhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDevelopmentDebug took 0.052000000 seconds
:baymax:incrementalDevelopmentDebugTasks
incrementalDevelopmentDebugTasks took 0.019000000 seconds
:baymax:preColdswapDevelopmentDebug
preColdswapDevelopmentDebug took 0.004000000 seconds
:baymax:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDevelopmentDebug
transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDevelopmentDebug took 0.974000000 seconds
:baymax:transformClassesWithDexForDevelopmentDebug


`**transformClassesWithDexForDevelopmentDebug took 29.440000000 seconds****<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`


:baymax:validateSigningDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebug
validateSigningDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebug took 0.007000000 seconds
:baymax:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDevelopmentDebug
transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDevelopmentDebug took 0.077000000 seconds
:baymax:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDevelopmentDebug


`**transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDevelopmentDebug took 1.007000000 seconds**<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`



:baymax:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDevelopmentDebug UP-TO-DATE
transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDevelopmentDebug took 0.018000000 seconds
:baymax:packageDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebug UP-TO-DATE
packageDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebug took 0.249000000 seconds
:baymax:buildInfoGeneratorDevelopmentDebug
buildInfoGeneratorDevelopmentDebug took 0.022000000 seconds
:baymax:assembleDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebug UP-TO-DATE
assembleDevelopmentArm64-v8aDebug took 0.008000000 seconds
:baymax:compileDevelopmentDebugSources
compileDevelopmentDebugSources took 0.003000000 seconds
:baymax:assembleDevelopmentDebug
assembleDevelopmentDebug took 0.001000000 seconds

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 28s
147 actionable tasks: 96 executed, 51 avoided (35%)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This video really helped https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ll-rkLCtyk me reduce my build time. There is an excellent blog post related to this video:https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-speed-up-your-slow-gradle-builds-5d9a9545f91a

I did following things to increase speed:

- Disable abi splits in development (You only need to do this if you are creating different apks based on CPU architecture):

  ```
  splits {
      abi {
          enable !project.hasProperty('devBuild')
      }
  }
  ```
- Disable png cruncher in development:

  ```
  android {
      if (project.hasProperty('devBuild')) {
          aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
      }
  }
  ```
- Don't modify `BuildConfig` every time when you hit run:

  ```
  def gitSha = project.hasProperty('devBuild') ? "gitSha_devBuild" : 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
  def buildTime = project.hasProperty('devBuild') ? "buildTime_devBuild" : new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
  ```

  and then later:

  ```
  buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
  buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime}\""
  ```
- Build against `minSdkVersion` 21 during development **and** only target the resources you need in your development device (in my case it was "en" and "xxhdpi"):

  ```
  productFlavors {
      fast {
          // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
          // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
          minSdkVersion 21
          //only package english translations, and xxhdpi resources
          resConfigs("en", "xxhdpi")
      }
      slow {
          // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
          minSdkVersion 16
      }
  }
  ```
- Move to `com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.X.X`

Now my build speed ranges from 10 seconds to 1 min!

Comment: Thanks for helping me realize what prevented my build from working with InstantRun were the BuildConfig constants!
Rather than using a `devBuild` flag, you could just declare the `buildConfigField`s separately for the `fast` and `slow` flavors (or `debug` and `release` build types).